# Assign value of textbox in Javascript and set the value in session with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, events

I've been struggling for a while with a Javascript/C# issue i have. I've been trying to set a Session variable from Javascript. I tried to use page methods before but it resulted in my javascript crashing.

In the javascript :

```
PageMethods.SetSession(id_Txt, onSuccess);
```

And this page method :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
public static string SetSession(string value)
{
    Page aPage = new Page();
    aPage.Session["id"] = value; 
    return value;
}
```

I haven't had any success with this. Therefore, i tried to set the value of a textbox from my javascript and put a OnTextChanged event in my c# to set the session variable but the event is not fired.

In the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('spanID').value = id_Txt;
```

In the html :

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" id="spanID" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="spanID_TextChanged"
style="visibility:hidden;"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the cs :

```
    protected void spanID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int projectID = Int32.Parse(dropdownProjects.SelectedValue);
        Session["id"] = projetID;
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea as of why none of my events where fired ? Do you have an alternative solution that I could try ?

Comment: Inside the static `WebMethod`, use `HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] = value;`

Comment: A common hack: Put a hidden asp button (`display:none`) and a hidden field. `OnClientClick` of the hidden button, set the hidden field. And inside the `OnClick` handler (cs), read the value from the hidden field. call js `$("#buttonId").click()` to fire the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, I didn't have the `enableSession = true` and i had to use the `HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] = value`, like stated by mshsayem. Now my event is fired properly and the session variable is set.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you have sessionState enabled (web.config):

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="10"/>
```

Second, ensure you have page-methods enabled:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Third, set session value like this (as the method is a static one):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["my_sessionValue"] = value;
```

Sample aspx:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setSessionValue() {
            PageMethods.SetSession("boss");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sc1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Button ID="btnSetSession" Text="Set Session Value (js)" runat="server" OnClientClick="setSessionValue();" />
<asp:Button ID="btnGetSession" Text="Get Session Value" runat="server" OnClick="ShowSessionValue" />
<br/>
<asp:Label ID="lblSessionText" runat="server" />
```

Sample code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(true)]
public static string SetSession(string value)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["my_sessionValue"] = value;
    return value;
}

protected void ShowSessionValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblSessionText.Text = Session["my_sessionValue"] as string;
}
```